# Add custom field during select mysql in laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have this query in laravel 5.2

```
$obj_custom_stdy_data = QstCustomStudyData::where('student_id', $this->data_user['student_id'])
                    ->select($list_id . ' as list_id ', 'chapter_id', 'subject_id', 'subject_code_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

Well I have a fixed value `$list_id` got from top code. Actually I want to add new field during query selection as `list_id`. However I got error for such that method.

When I tried in mysql IDE for example:

```
SELECT (1+2) as total, c.* FROM users
```

Then the result is no wrong at all.

Is that anyway to write in query builder for laravel instead of `raw` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the use of `DB::raw()` method of QueryBuilder like this:

```
->select(DB::raw('(1+2) as total'));
```

> See more about [Query Builder's Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Very fast response.

Comment: Thanks, Glad to see that it helps you to resolve your problem!